# While executing this sync function getting error as Object Required dictObj

Tags: scripting, qtp

```
Sub sb_Web_Sync(webObject,objDesc)
    Set webObject = dictObj.Item(webObject)
    mercurytimers.Timer ("sb_Web_Sync").Start
    Do
        Services.ThinkTime 1
    Loop Until webObject.Object.readyState = "complete" and webObject.Object.documentElement.readyState = "complete"

    Do 
         Services.ThinkTime 1
    Loop Until webObject.Frame("html tag:=IFRAME","Class Name:=Frame","url:=about:blank").Exist(0) = false Or (mercurytimers.Timer ("sb_Web_Sync").ElapsedTime >=2000)

    mercurytimers.Timer ("sb_Web_Sync").Reset
    mercurytimers.Timer ("sb_Web_Sync").Stop
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and have a look at [ask]. This is not `VB.NET` code. Please use the correct tag.

Answer (score 0):

dictObj object in the above function is not pointing to any object.
You have to create the reference to that object for which your intending to point.

For example:
If you intend to point to some page then use the below statement:
Set dictObj = Browser("micClass:=Browser","creationtime:=0").Page("micClass:=Page")

Probably the webObject/objDesc which is passed as parameter to this function should have the object described. Please check the calling 
statement once.

Hope this will answer your question.

Thanks,
Nandana